# Fill an area under a line in Python Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

How to shade the area under a line in Bokeh?

I have a simple line plot as follows and I want to fill an under a line in a specified color.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import output_file, curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

output_file("layout.html")


df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ["1-1-2019", "2-1-2019", "3-1-2019", "4-1-2019", "5-1-2019", "6-1-2019", "7-1-2019", "8-1-2019", "9-1-2019", "10-1-2019"],
                   'cost': [10, 15, 20, 30, 25, 5, 15, 30, 35, 25]})

fig = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", toolbar_location='above', plot_width=1500)

plot_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(date=pd.to_datetime(df["date"]),
                                         cost=df["cost"]))

line_plot = fig.line("date", "cost", source=plot_source, line_width=2, color="#00CED1")

show(fig)
```

So it will look like a green area in the image below.

[image]

I checked `Pathces` glyph function however I am not clear about it. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Maybe Bands? https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#bands

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
band = Band(base='date', upper='cost', source=plot_source, level='underlay',
            fill_alpha=0.2, fill_color='#55FF88')
fig.add_layout(band)
```

Edit: `fill_alpha=0.2, fill_color='#55FF88'` seem to be closer to the example

A complete example looks like:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import output_file, curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Band

output_file("layout.html")
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ["1-1-2019", "2-1-2019", "3-1-2019", "4-1-2019", "5-1-2019", "6-1-2019", "7-1-2019", "8-1-2019", "9-1-2019", "10-1-2019"],
                   'cost': [10, 15, 20, 30, 25, 5, 15, 30, 35, 25]})
fig = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", toolbar_location='above', plot_width=1500)
plot_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(date=pd.to_datetime(df["date"]),
                                         cost=df["cost"]))
line_plot = fig.line("date", "cost", source=plot_source, line_width=2, color="#00CED1")
band = Band(base='date', upper='cost', source=plot_source, level='underlay',
            fill_alpha=0.2, fill_color='#55FF88')
fig.add_layout(band)
show(fig)
```

The generated plot: [image: Generated plot]

PS: The Band annotation doesn't have support for the legend. To get a legend, replace the Band with the `varea` glyph as proposed by @bigreddot. In your code:

```py
fig.varea(source=plot_source, x="date", y1=0, y2="cost",
          alpha=0.2, fill_color='#55FF88', legend_label="cost")
```

Comment: This returns an empty layout.

Comment: The error was related to the bokeh version, after updating it, it worked. 
Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to add a legend for Band object?

Answer (score 6):

`Band` is an option but [`varea`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#single-areas) is probably better as it is a glyph rather than an annotation, and also supports stacking with [`varea_stack`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#stacked-areas), if you need stacking.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

p.varea(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        y1=0, y2=[1, 4, 2, 2, 3], alpha=0.6)

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: It returns a following error: "AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'varea'"

Comment: The error is because of the bokeh version, after updating, it worked as well. Thank you so much for help!

Comment: This one is better if the legend wants to be added for the plot compared to band.